# Configure TeamCity for gradle multi project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, teamcity, jetbrains-ide, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multi project gradle, which I configured as follows:

[image]

- red arrow: root gradle
- green arrow: access project
- purple arrow: commons
- blue arrow: company project

The entire project is in a repository (main) and each subproject I set up a git subtree and has its own repository. I'm trying to configure automatic deploy but I couldn't, not even do a gradle clean. I made the configuration as follows:

[image]

my root gradle:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.*
plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") apply false
  kotlin("plugin.serialization") apply false
  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") apply false
  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") apply false
  id("org.flywaydb.flyway") apply false
  `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.rjdesenvolvimento"
version = "0.0.1"

subprojects {
  group = "com.rjdesenvolvimento"
  version = "0.0.1"

  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor") { name = "bintray-ktor" }
    maven(url = "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/")
    maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
  }

  afterEvaluate {
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")) {
      tasks {
        withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
          kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
        withType<io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt> {
          this.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
        withType<Test> {
          useJUnitPlatform()
          testLogging {
            events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
          }
        }
      }
      publishing {
        publications {
          create<MavenPublication>("mavenKotlin") {
            from(components["kotlin"])
            pom {
              licenses {
                license {
                  name.set("The Apache License, Version 2.0")
                  url.set("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the gradle of the subproject I'm using in teamcity

```
plugins {
  application
  kotlin("jvm")
  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")
  id("org.flywaydb.flyway")
  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")
  `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.rjdesenvolvimento"
version = "0.0.1"

application {
  mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven { url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor") }
  maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
}

dependencies {
  implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:_")
  implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:_")
  implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:_")
  implementation("io.ktor:ktor-jackson:_")
  implementation(project(":commons:commons.consumer"))
  implementation(project(":commons:commons.patterns"))
  implementation(project(":commons:commons.kafka"))
  implementation(project(":commons:commons.elasticsearch"))

  testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:_")
  testImplementation(project(":commons:commons.test"))
}

kotlin.sourceSets["main"].kotlin.srcDirs("src")
kotlin.sourceSets["test"].kotlin.srcDirs("test")

sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("resources")
sourceSets["test"].resources.srcDirs("testresources")

detekt {
  buildUponDefaultConfig = false
  input = files("src")
  config = files("resources/detekt.yml")
  debug = true
  ignoreFailures = false
  reports {
    xml {
      enabled = true
      destination = file("build/reports/detekt.xml")
    }
    html {
      enabled = true
      destination = file("build/reports/detekt.html")
    }
    txt {
      enabled = true
      destination = file("build/reports/detekt.txt")
    }
    custom {
      reportId = "CustomJsonReport"
      destination = file("build/reports/detekt.json")
    }
  }
}

flyway {
  url = System.getenv("URL")
  user = System.getenv("PSQL_USER")
  password = System.getenv("PSQL_PASSWORD")
  baselineOnMigrate = true
  locations = arrayOf("filesystem:resources/db/migration")
}
```

When I try to run, it shows an error that the agent is not compatible with the configuration.
What should I do? Could anyone help?

to better understand, github with the project. https://github.com/rodrigodevelms/Proof-of-concept

Update: image error:
[image]

Update 2:

I added a gradle wrapper and the following error happens:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post error that you are seing?

Comment: @EvgenyBovykin - updated with image. 
I have 2 registered agents. If I use this same configuration in a project that is not "multi-project", it works perfectly

Comment: In your configuration settings, you can go to `Agent Requirements` tag. There you will see a reason why each agent is considered incompatible

Comment: @EvgenyBovykin - Sorry I'm late. I lost two uncles to Covid, it was a tough month. Updated

Comment: You need to specify version of kotlin plugin: `kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"` (or whatever version you actually use)

Comment: What is shown on [this](https://imgur.com/a/Nmzkp2Q) page?